# Display a value that may be copied but not modified (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I want to display a calculated result that can be copied to pasted elsewhere (e.g., another app), but that can not be edited/modified.  I would also like to indicate if that result has more character than fit in the view.

Is it better to use a UILabel, UIButton, UITextField, or UITextView?

So far, the only one I've found to work is the UITextView by setting:

```
textView.isEditable = false
textView.isEditable.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

However, as an example, the view initially appears like this:
[image], which seems to indicate that the result is 8,872,750 - there is no indication that there may be more digits.

In fact, the actual result is 8,872,750,000,000,000,000,000.

If I double-click on the textview, I get:
[image] and can copy the contents.

Clicking elsewhere then back in the textview, I get:
[image].  While I can scroll by dragging the cursor up or down, I can not if using up or down arrows.

On the other hand, a UITextField shows like this: [image].  The contents may be copied - but they may also be modified or deleted.

How do I display a result that may be copied, may not be modified, and gives some indication if the value extends beyond the view?

Comment: How about a text field that refuses to let you modify or delete its text?

Comment: You can also add a copy button besides a label and add the text to the pasteboard programmatically `UIPasteboard.general.string = "8,872,750,000,000,000,000,000"`

Comment: @matt - how do not allow modifying or deleting text in a text field while also making it selectable to copy it contents?

Comment: @Leo Dabus - There are a lot of fields on several screens, so if I understand correctly, that would be unwieldy.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a `UITextView` with `isSelectable` set to true and `isEditable` set to false.

A text view can be set up to add a scroll bar if desired.

Comment: This works great for a textview with vertical scrolling (though I haven't yet figured out how to leave the scroll bar always visible when the contents exceed the height), but, although I have `textview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true', it is not working.  (Am I missing something?)

Comment: Also, is there a way to show when there are more digits than displayed?